# How to determine VirtualBox vm has finished snapshot restore

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, virtual-machine, snapshot

I have a ubuntu host and a windows 10 guest using virtualbox.
And I have written a bash script to control my vm.
I want to shutdown my vm and restore snapshot, then restart it.
But here is a question.
When I run the code like this:

```
VBoxManage snapshot $vmid restore $snapshotname
VBoxManage startvm $vmid
```

It will have an error that is about the vm session is locked after the second command ran.

Is there any code that can wait until the snapshot restore of the vm is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution will be to add a wait in the script for a long-enough
time for the restore to complete.

The more complex solution would be to use
[VirtualBox Main API - IConsole Interface Reference](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/interface_i_console.html)
in some supported programming language.

The following C# example comes from the post
[How to restore a snapshot with virtualbox api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441372/165358):

```
VirtualBox.VirtualBox virtualBox = new VirtualBox.VirtualBox();
IMachine vmMachine = virtualBox.FindMachine("Windows 8");
Session session = new Session();
vmMachine.LockMachine(session, LockType.LockType_Shared);
IConsole console = session.Console;

// Restore snapshot
ISnapshot snapShot = vmMachine.FindSnapshot("Snapshot 1");

IProgress snapShotProgress = console.RestoreSnapshot(snapShot);
snapShotProgress.WaitForCompletion(300000);

// unlock before launch VMProcess
session.UnlockMachine();

IProgress launchVmProgess = vmMachine.LaunchVMProcess(session, "gui", "None");

launchVmProgess.WaitForCompletion(300000);
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! I use python to implement